# How iteration last to first in HashMap?

Tags: java

I have HashMAp

```
 items = new HashMap<String, String>();
        items.put("A", "1");
        items.put("B", "2");
        items.put("C", "3");
```

I need for each last to first.

```
"C", "3"
"B", "2"
"A", "1"
```

Comment: The terms Last and First seem to denote time. Most of the answers I see assume Last and First are semantic (e.g. C is larger than A and thus Last). OrderedMaps won't help you if you need insertion time ordering and don't have the insertion timestamp in the key.

Comment: `HashMap` doesn't guarantee any order for its elements. In particular, it doesn't guarantee that the order remains constant over time. Thus, `HashMap` is not what you want if you have to maintain any kind of order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Myself and Matthew clearly have different interpretations of what your question means. Do you mean reverse order that you inserted, or reverse order of keys?

If you mean reverse order of keys, here's how to do it:

Use an ordered Map, like TreeMap and then iterate over items.keySet().

TreeMap sorts by natural order of your key values, so you will need to pass in a comparator to the constructor to sort the keys in reverse order:

```
Map<String, String> items = new TreeMap<String, String>(new Comparator<String>() {
  public int compare(String a, String b) {
    return b.compareTo(a);
  }
});

items.put("A", "1");
items.put("B", "2");
items.put("C", "3");

for (String s: items.keySet()) {
  System.out.println(s + " " + items.get(s));
}
```

Comment: This code is equivalent : `Map<String, String> items = new TreeMap<String, String>(Collections.reverseOrder());`

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [`NavigableMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) ([`TreeMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is a `NavigableMap`), which is a `SortedMap` with navigation capabilities.

[`NavigableMap#descendingMap()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#descendingMap()) returns a reverse order view (not a copy) of the mappings contained in this map.

Example :

```
NavigableMap<String, String> items = new TreeMap<String, String>();
items.put("B", "2");
items.put("A", "1");
items.put("C", "3");

for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : items.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
// gives
// A=1
// B=2
// C=3

for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : items.descendingMap().entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(e);
}

// gives
// C=3
// B=2
// A=1
```

Note : This answer is valid if you care about the *natural ordering* of the keys in your `Map`. If you care about the insertion ordering or the access ordering, then have a look at `LinkedHashMap`.

Note 2 : In your question, you used a `HashMap`. Please note that `HashMap` doesn't guarantee any order for its elements. Actually, it doesn't even guarantee the order will remain constant over time. See the first paragraph of `HashMap`'s [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) for further references.

Comment: The order is based on key semantics. But I think the question is about insertion time. So a reverse order won't help you as the order criterium (insertion time) is not part of the key.

Comment: I added a note to clarify things

Answer (score 1):

HashMap doesn't guarantee *any* ordering.  If you use [`LinkedHashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), it will be ordered by insertion, but there is still no convenient way to go backwards.

One way would be to call `items.entrySet()`.  That returns a `Set<Map.Entry>`.  You can then get the size of the set, call `toArray()`, then do a descending for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Another method - create a SortedSet of your keys:

```
import java.util.*;

class MyComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        return -a.compareTo(b);
    }

    public boolean equals(String a, String b) {
        return a.equals(b);
    }
}

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, String> items = new HashMap<String, String>();
        items.put("A", "1");
        items.put("B", "2");
        items.put("C", "3");

        TreeSet<String> ts = new TreeSet<String>(new MyComparator());
        ts.addAll(items.keySet());
        for(Iterator<String> i = ts.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            String key = i.next();
            System.out.println("key: " + key + ", value: " + items.get(key));
        }
    }
}
```

**output:**

```
key: C, value: 3
key: B, value: 2
key: A, value: 1
```

Comment: You assume Last is in the context of the key, but I think he meant insertion time. If the insertion time is not in the key a comparator cannot help you.

Comment: I disagree. I don't think insertion time has anything to do with it. I think he made the mistake of thinking a HashMap could be iterated in some order, and wants it reversed. I'm assuming the order he meant was alphabetical.